# Separate date and year in a particular column to another columns with date and year in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
|Month|
|---|
|April'18|
|May'19|
```

What I am trying to do is

```
|Month|Year|
|---|---|
|Apr|2018|
|May|2019|
```

Is there any way to do that in pandas...I got stuck while handling the dataframe.
Thanks in advance. Please let me know if i have made clear what my question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with convert values to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `%B` for match month names and `%y` for match `YY` and between `'` and then use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format="%B'%y")

df['Month'] = s.dt.strftime('%b')
df['Year'] = s.dt.year
```

Or if possible all year greater like `1999` is possible indexing first 3 and last 2 values with add `20`:

```
df = df.assign(Month = df['Month'].str[:3],
               Year = ('20' + df['Month'].str[-2:]).astype(int))
print (df)
  Month  Year
0   Apr  2018
1   May  2019
```

Comment: thanks a ton mate...how you have created the code so fast ...hats off man...it really worked smoothly without any errors. Thanks again. God bless u